# How can i set a cron job in Zpanel

Tags: php, cron, cakephp-2.0

in C panel  we can set url in cron job like

> > wget example.com/homes/action

Or 
absolute path

> > /usr/bin/php -q /home/mohanphp/www/quote_bot/sms_cron.php

but  Zpanel  dose not support  full url

and i want to call an action  (in Cakephp eg http://abc.com/homes/corn_job/daily/ )

in c panel there is no problem but Zpenal how to do this ??

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can better check the link [set a cron job in Zpanel](http://planet.zpanelcp.com?id=zpanel_x%3aarticles%3ainstallation%3aubuntu_11.10_manual_installation#setup_the_cron_job_for_the_zdaemon).

```
touch /etc/cron.d/zdaemon
echo "*/5 * * * * root /usr/bin/php -q /etc/zpanel/panel/bin/daemon.php >> /dev/null 2>&1" >> /etc/cron.d/zdaemon
chmod 644 /etc/cron.d/zdaemon
```

Comment: yes , but i want to set web url like example.com/homes/action

Comment: Downvote for the answer given as it's not answered @YogeshSaroya 's question fully

Comment: @Paul We are here for guiding, making suggestions. I couldn't undertand your downvote....aaah anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to run the URL, just because you want to run an action of a cakephp controller. Then you should try to use a dispatcher, which will let you execute a controller action from the command prompt and then you can setup the cron as normal in zpanel.

More information about the cron dispatcher could be found here:
http://colorblindprogramming.com/cronjobs-in-cakephp-2-in-5-steps